# Are all of today's horn-rimmed glasses vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

So called **horn-rimmed glasses** seem to be getting popular again. Is it safe to assume that these glasses are all vegan and only made out of plastic nowadays, or are some producers still using actual horn?

Comment: Geez. I'm embarrassed to admit that _only now_ do I realize how they got their name originally.

Comment: Buffalo horn is still used in a lot of applications, and even considered a premium material compared to plastic - which annoys the hell out of me as a knife collector :)

Comment: @Erica given that nothing about horn rimmed glasses is pointy, or a musical instrument, there are not that many origins left for the name :)

Comment: Not only horn, but also tortoise shells :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not safe to assume they are plastic.  Though I think price might be a good indicator.

> Many designer glasses are produced in their thousands, but RIGARDS’s are made in their ones. RIGARDS frames are constructed of horn

http://rigards.com/genuine-horn

There are others, but that answers your question.

Comment: Since horn is an expensive prestige material though, might it be safe to assume that the glasses are plastic if the manufacturer doesn't mention the use of "real horn" as a *selling point*?

Comment: @Zanna I completely agree with you and I do mention that price might be a good indicator.  But the question is whether it is safe to assume they are plastic - it isn't.

Comment: Yeah I guess this helps somewhat :/